# Make Google Chrome Extension Automatically Pop Up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google chrome extension. Is there a way to use javascript to make the extension automatically pop-up every time I switch to a new tab without having to click on the icon?

Comment: You can open new window when tab is created like that:
```javascript
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(() => {
    chrome.windows.create({url: '/filename.html', width: 450, height: 600, type: 'popup'})
})
```

Comment: I tried putting the code in my js file with the correct html name but it does not make the extension pop up when I change tabs.

Comment: onCreated is fired when new tab is created. Other events you can find on https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/

Comment: If by "pop up" you're referring to the `browserAction` popup, then you can't. Only the user can open if, either via click or keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I am sure it is possible since I use the Honey extension and it automatically pops up at checkout. I am trying to recreate that

Comment: "it automatically pops up at checkout.." (sorry I don't use honey) >> do you mean the window in top right corner that opens for some extensions when extension icon is clicked [see image](https://wd.imgix.net/image/BhuKGJaIeLNPW9ehns59NfwqKxF2/ku5Z8MMssgw6MKctpJVI.png)? This is what the term "popup" refers to for browser extensions, and it is not programmatically openable since there is no API for it (honey may have some very custom hack for it, I mean they sold for 4B...). But if the intent is to open some type of window/modal/view in the active browser tab, then that is easily doable.

Comment: Yes, I want to open my extension in the active browser tab using javascript like the image you linked. Is there any code or example that I can use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your javascript to be injected into every page (and then you decide if you want to do a in page popup from there). You would use content scripts.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#functionality

Comment: Thanks, so I add this into my manifest file correct? What javascript code would make the extension pop up?

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for you, it is to create a sticky dialog container, create it from your contents.js, make the container style a fixed position.

In ES5 syntax:

```
var container = document.createElement('div')
container.style.position = "fixed"
container.style.height = "50px"
container.style.width = " 100px"
container.style.top = "0px"
container.style.right = "0px"
container.style.border = "1px solid black"
container.style.backgroundColor = "white"
document.body.appendChild(container)
```